# Passing data from Controller to jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I basically want to pass data from my controller into my JSP to pass data trough my application. 
Main idea is to get data per URL and send i to an service method. I want to use it to simply change a password.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/passwordSetForm")
public String redirectToPasswordForm(@RequestParam(value = "token") String token) {

    log.debug("+++++token: '{}'",token);
    return "form"; 
}
```

Return the form to change the password, identification per token.

JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Set Password/title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form name="f" action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/setPassword" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        <input class="field" type='text' id="password" name='password' size="20" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="${ token }" />      
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2' align="center">
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="SET" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to pass the token trough into the next controller method. But I only getting a variable and not the token value. Am I forgetting an import or something ?
Thx for any help.

Comment: It is not advisable to use POST methods when you are dealing with password information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="<%= request.getParameter("token") %>" />
```